# Rails page rendering time in a development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm just going to keep this question simple. In my rails console I see this:

```
Completed 200 OK in 2261ms (Views: 564.1ms | ActiveRecord: 40.7ms)
```

Where do the 1656 milliseconds (2261 - 564 - 40) come from? Precompiling assets? This is in a dev environment.

Comment: I doubt it's precompiling; this I think has to happen before your server will see the action. I'd guess largely controller code -- is it possible you have some inefficient loops or slow operations inside your controllers?

Comment: I'm using a gem called filterrific that helped me a lot for filtering and searching objects, so It might be a controller issue as you say, I'll look into it. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Assets aren't compiled on every request, but only when the asset itself is requested and it has changed on file.

Comment: This is the rendering time.